# neo4j kafka batch processor

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-java-api

I have a spring-kafka based consumer which processes the connection/edge records to neo4j, with batch size 100.

What is the best way to implement batching using neo4j java sdk?

Requirement:

- Caller should know which edge/connection got created successfully and which got failed?

Clarification:
One reason why edge creation may fail is if one of source or destination node is not yet created, then edge creation will fail!

Thanks In Advance!